# Creating time window around a date

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to create a time window around a given date. Other questions have centred around having a start and end date, the only thing I have is one date which I would like to create an window around.  Currently, I have a df with multiple dates in it and an ID, I would like to create time windows around the dates ranging from -2 to +2. The outcome should be stored in a df format so that I can join values from another df to it. The actual dataset is a lot larger so manually entering start and end dates for all the ID is not really an option.

```
df1 = 
ID    Date
56   2016-05-22
894  2016-11-09
```

ending up with a df similar to below

```
ID      date
56      2016-05-20
56      2016-05-21
56      2016-05-22
56      2016-05-23
56      2016-05-24
894     2016-11-07
894     2016-11-08
894     2016-11-09
894     2016-11-10
894     2016-11-11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `complete` from `tidyr` which makes it easy to complete sequences, i.e.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
 mutate(Date = as.Date(Date)) %>% 
 group_by(ID) %>% 
 complete(Date = seq.Date((Date-2), (Date+2), by = 'days'))
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 10 x 2
> # Groups:   ID [2]
>       ID Date      
>    <int> <date>    
>  1    56 2016-05-20
>  2    56 2016-05-21
>  3    56 2016-05-22
>  4    56 2016-05-23
>  5    56 2016-05-24
>  6   894 2016-11-07
>  7   894 2016-11-08
>  8   894 2016-11-09
>  9   894 2016-11-10
> 10   894 2016-11-11
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a fast `data.table` solution

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, .(date = seq(as.Date(Date) - 2, as.Date(Date) + 2, 1)), by = ID]
#     ID       date
# 1:  56 2016-05-20
# 2:  56 2016-05-21
# 3:  56 2016-05-22
# 4:  56 2016-05-23
# 5:  56 2016-05-24
# 6: 894 2016-11-07
# 7: 894 2016-11-08
# 8: 894 2016-11-09
# 9: 894 2016-11-10
#10: 894 2016-11-11
```

---

### Sample data

```
df1 <- read.table(text = " ID    Date
56   2016-05-22
894  2016-11-09", header = T)
```

Answer (score 1):

A `base R` option would be to loop through the 'Date' column, get the sequence in a `list`, then `rep`licate the 'ID' based on the `lengths` of 'list' to create a new 'data.frame' while concatenating the `list` elements

```
lst1 <- lapply(df1$Date, function(x) seq(x-2, x+2, by = '1 day'))
data.frame(ID = rep(df1$ID, lengths(lst1)), date = do.call(c, lst1))
#    ID       date
#1   56 2016-05-20
#2   56 2016-05-21
#3   56 2016-05-22
#4   56 2016-05-23
#5   56 2016-05-24
#6  894 2016-11-07
#7  894 2016-11-08
#8  894 2016-11-09
#9  894 2016-11-10
#10 894 2016-11-11
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(56L, 894L), Date = structure(c(16943, 17114
 ), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```